# Checkbox status clears after review

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Picture first to show the interaction with the interface...
[image]

This is an interface that I am building which enables the editing of one column in the database for multiple rows. This function works perfectly except for the fact that after making the first edit you can't go back and make another edit.

When you choose the Edit Selected button to pop up the panel for the second time. The panel doesn't pop up.

The reason why it doesn't pop up is because in the code below  is no longer 'true' even though the checkboxes on the GridView remain checked.

```
if (((CheckBox)grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).Checked == true)
```

I haven't been able to figure out why the checked value is no longer true the second pass.

When the user selects the 'Save' on the edit panel it touches off a SP which performs the update of the table.

Here the relevant portion of the GridView definition:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ActVulListGV" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ActVulListGV_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="25" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#ccffff" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="25" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RecID" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCFF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" DataSourceID="Vul_DS">
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Details" EditText="Edit Row"></asp:CommandField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tag" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="TagRowChkBx" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- 13 addtional BoundFields -->
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Next here is the segment of code that is checking for the boxes to be checked (or not) which is preventing to allow the panel to become visible after the first go around.

```
protected void EditSelctedBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Read the column select drop down List into Local Varriables 
  String SelectedColumnItem = ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
  String SelectedColumnValue = ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString();

  List<int> EditRows = new List<int>();
  List<string> recordnumber = new List<string>();
  int rcounter = 0;
  foreach (GridViewRow grv in ActVulListGV.Rows)
    {
  // Here is where 'true' becomes not true on second pass
      if (((CheckBox)grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).Checked == true)  
    {
   rcounter++;

   //get current row rowindex if  checkbox  in it is checked 
   EditRows.Add(grv.RowIndex);
   //get the record number (RecID)
   recordnumber.Add(grv.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
 }
```

Hopefully someone might be able to suggest what may be causing this so I can use the function more than once per page display.
Thanks, Ken...

Update 05/23/2017 2:20PM Central US:

This continues to baffle me beyond reason.

I took into account that it might be the post back taking place during the databind of the gridview to display the changes made to the table by the SP. I built a routine to capture the state and reestablish it after the binding is completed. Works well...  But I still have the same issue of the value of the checkboxes not reading as they are displaying on the second time around the 'Edit Selected' button.

Since I was only checking for 'true' on reading the value of the checkbox I thought maybe I should attempt to determine what the actual value is so I added a else if it is true and else to catch anything that isn't true or false (See code below).

Did nothing for me as well!  so I put a break point in and observed what happened for the second pass...

What I found was that as soon as the first line below executed the flow completely bypassed the remainder of this code. So not only was it not true, it wasn't false, and it wasn't something other than false.  I think I've discovered dark matter in C# code!

```
if (((CheckBox)grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).Checked == true)
{
    //get current row rowindex if  checkbox  in it is checked 
    EditRows.Add(grv.RowIndex);
    //get the record number (RecID)
    recordnumber.Add(grv.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
    }
}
else if (((CheckBox)grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).Checked == false)
{
    UserMessageLbl.Text = "CheckBox value = false!!!";
    PopUpPnl.Visible = true;
    }
else
    {
    UserMessageLbl.Text = "CheckBox value neither true or false = "+ (((CheckBox)grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).ToString());
    PopUpPnl.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: sounds like UpdatePanel / Postback Issue..

Comment: Not checking for PostBack at this point since this is being triggered by the click of the 'Edit Selected' button. I don't see how PostBack status would have an impact on the state of a Checkbox.  If someone knows of a command syntax to ignore PostBack status I'm more than willing to give it a try. I'm not aware of one.

Comment: perhaps you should read up on what controls trigger postbacks then huh..?

Comment: @MethodMan I'm not using 'UpdatePanel' (as in Ajax extension) if that was your reference.  I am using standard asp:Panel's.

Comment: Updated question with additional comments 5/23/2017 2:20 Central US.